# Why I am not able to access my hostname from anywhere but the local server?

Tags: vpn, iis-7, remote-desktop, hosting, coldfusion

I created a website on an IIS server with hostname 'www.cftest.local'

When I access the website from the IIS server it renders my content as expected.

But when I try to access this from my local machine, the browser says 'This webpage is not available'.

Why I am not able to access my website using the said hostname from anywhere but the IIS server?

Comment: Can you do something like `curl -v http://www.cftest.local` and post the result in order to determine where the error lies?

Comment: @Daniel.Amkaer: Is this possible what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because that domain doesn't exist on DNS Servers. There can be two ways to access your website:

1. Register the domain with a DNS Provider and map that DNS with the IP of remote server.
2. Map the stated domain to the IP of Remote Server in your host file.

I'll recommend you need more about Domains and DNS. A good start can be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: Means this is not possible without registering this domain with DNS provider??

Comment: No. Hostnname needs to be resolved to an IP. Either you do it on your system by adding an entry to your local machine's host file or you put it on DNS Servers so that any one on internet calling that Hostname can  get an IP as resolution.

Comment: @user3427540: if you find the answer satisfactory, request you to mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Thanks , your second solution worked for me . I have changed my host file to point the domain to the ip of remote server.